# how to post and get data using php and codeigniter without page reload

Tags: php, codeigniter, php-5.3

I am beginner in codeigniter MVC.

**Question:** How to send and receive data using codeigniter and PHP without page refresh or reload.

**NOTE:** Please give some MVC examples using either ajax or jquery or both.

Comment: You'll need to use AJAX > https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX

Comment: frnd, i knew how to use normally.But in CodeIgniter MVC normal isn't working.So Please can u give me any CodeIgniter MVC examples using ajax or jquery.

Comment: No. That's what Google is for. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

There are many tutorials in google about this.
But here is the simple example using CodeIgniter and Jquery:

1. Create a file named `test_controller.php` in your controller folder. Put this code:

   ```
   <?php
   class Test_controller extends CI_Controller {
           public function index() 
           {
                   $this->load->view("test_view"); 
           }

           public function do_ajax()
           {
                   $name=$this->input->post("name"); //get posted data
                   echo "Hello $name, I am AJAX"; //return response
           }

   }
   ```
2. Create a file named test_view in your View folder. Put this code:

   ```
   <html>
           <head>
                   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                   <script>
                           function getpost_ajax() {
                                   var name=$("#name").val();

                                   //begin ajax
                                   $.post("<?php echo site_url('stack/test_controller/do_ajax'); ?>", { 
                                           //data to post
                                           name:name
                                   }, function(data){
                                           //on success, alert the data
                                           alert(data)                                                        
                                   });
                           }
                   </script>
           </head>
           <body>
                   <input type="text" id="name" />
                   <input type="button" onclick="getpost_ajax()" value="GO!"/>
           </body>
   </html>
   ```
3. Open in your browser: `http://localhost/your_site_folder/index.php/test_controller`. Fill the textbox with any data, and then click GO!. It will post the data from the textbox, and alert the response.